# require.js and restricted access resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs, amd

I have a webapp using Backbone and jquery, that uses require.js (+ text and css plugin) to load the dependencies.
So I have a structure such as:

```
root
  |-widgets 
  |    |--widget1-Widget1.js
                |-widget.html 
  |-views
  |    |--view1-View1.js
  |           |-view.html
  |-app.js
```

using Require.js I can compose nicely my app keeping views and widgets quite isolated.

The problem is that I need to restrict the access to some views to some user having admin role.

I can already protect the REST layer on the backend side only to some roles.
I would also like to forbid the access to the views and business logic of the app itself, preventing from loading certain Views and Widgets.

How can I achieve that with Require.js ?

My idea is to AJAX load the script with Jquery, then if the user is unhautorized, manage it nicely on the app level.
Then I wonder what can I do out of the loaded script.
How can I attach it nicely to the page without breaking the philosophy of Require, and the structure of the whole application?

Is there an already built-in solution I can use without reinventing the wheel, or am I doing the wrong way?